# error_css_class doesnt apply to django form without {{form.as_p}}

Tags: html, css, django, error-handling

I have a form with one variable 'var1':

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class='error'
    var1=forms.IntegerField(label='var1',widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id':'id_var1',
                                                                         'name':'var1'))
    
    def clean_var1(self):
        var1=self.cleaned_data.get("var1")
        if var1 == 2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('cant be 2!')
        return var1
```

and styled  the error message:

```
<style>
    .errorlist { 
            list-style-type: none; 
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
    }
    .errorlist li {  /* Style each error message */
        color: red;     
    }
    .error {   /* the label of the field */
        color:red;
    }
    .error input{   /* the text field */
        border: 2px solid red;   
    } 
</style>
```

When i render the form using {{form.as_p}} everything works correctly,
but when i render it manualy like this

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <P>{{ form.var1.label_tag }} {{ form.var1 }} {{ form.var1.errors }}</P>
        </div>
        <button type="submit", name="calculate">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

the class "error" isnt applied to the fields.

i know i can use an 'if' statement to add a class to each paragraph but i wonder whats the problem with what i did.

thanks for the help!